# How to convert a list of objects into a JSON object using a property as key?

Tags: java, json

I have a `List` of objects from a specific class which have a `name` field. I'm trying to convert this list into a JSON object where the property key will be the `name` of this field and the value is always set to `null`.

My final JSON should look like this:

```json
{
  "Java": null,
  "React": null,
  "Spring": null
}
```

My class looks like this:

```java
public class Tag {
    private Long id;
    private String name; // Java, Spring, React

    // setters and getters omited
}
```

I tried to convert it using the below code:

```java
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(tagList);
```

But this just returns a JSON array of objects.

How can I convert my list into the above mentioned structure?

Comment: What's the meaning of *I don't understand how to make field's value to field, and set his value to null*? Please be specific and clear.

Comment: @Ivar The update with JSON is just to make people now that I know that Jackson exists in this world.  I just asked to get help "How to convert to specific json" cause I don't know how.

Comment: Use a Jackson custom serializer or use JSON library where you have the complete freedom.

Comment: @fiveelements I want to get that result {
   "Java": null,
  "React": null,
  "Google": null
 } So in java object Tag field is "name" and his values is "JAVA, REACT, SPRING"/ But in result these values becomes json fields

Comment: @Ivar Yes. Finally someone got what I want to do :)

Comment: @airush  i have updated the answer to produce desired JSON using `json` library. Please take a look.

Comment: @airush I've rewritten your question a bit to better show what you are asking. If you mind you can always roll it back.

Comment: @Ivar Thanks, I had to do that earlier :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use `json` library and create the JSON by hand or use a higher-level library such as `Jackson` or `Gson`.

Based on the updated question, here is the code based on `json` library that produces the desired output:

```
{"Java":null,"Spring":null}
```

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TagConverter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
        Tag t1 = new Tag("Java");
        Tag t2 = new Tag("Spring");
        tags.add(t1);
        tags.add(t2);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        for(Tag t : tags){
            json.put(t.name, JSONObject.NULL);
        }

        System.out.println(json);
    }

    private static class Tag{
        public Long id;
        public String name;

        public Tag(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Either add a maven dependency or get the library from `maven`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It is not answer at all. Question is not "what to use to convert java obj to json"

Comment: Perhaps you did not see the initial question. The original question was - how to convert the given Java object to JSON. Later he updated to add the specific issues. Maybe that's the reason you are thinking this way :).

Comment: Oh, I did not realize :)

Comment: @fiveelements Thank you for your answer, before I stupidly created that JSON by StringBuilder.  That's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you should convert your object to a **key-value Map** first while the key is the value of the name field *(This can't be duplicated, duplication resulting in overriding the previous value)*, and value could be **NULL** for your case and then convert the map to JSON.